# Formal words for "make a stride"?

Tags: formality

I came across "make a stride" while I read some articles about global climate change. However, I am not sure if that is formal enough to use in writing an academic essay. If not, what are the formal words for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is formal and instead of make a stride you can use;

advance considerably, make substantial progress or decisive progress.

'Make a stride' is usually used with 'great' as in' make a great stride'.

Comment: In terms of Climate Change, I would use such an expression *with a lot of caution* ... it is the sort of phrase a government media release might contain, and quite often such phrases are used precisely because they are difficult to quantify. I would not use it in an academic paper - other than to "quote" other sources, and in the process of running a critique of the claimed progress made (in Climate Change policies or anything else). So I would avoid it because it can be seen as effusive, as much as being a bit informal for a paper.

Comment: You are right. Stride has 'great' meaning in it. I have never used 'make a stride' but '... advanced considerably in the past years' and '... made substantial progress in ...' on the papers I have written.